# How to select date from date picker using selenium web driver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to select date from below calendar. Where there is no td available.Also input field click  tag is visible and if try select it, getting disappear. Now, how can I get locator of date? or how can I select any date from it?

[image]

Here is below HTML code snippets.

[image]

ngui-datepicker tag is visible on the click on input field.

[image]

Comment: Can you right click on the text input file and click "Inspect Element" to bring up the browser debug console? Then maybe you can see the calendar HTML structure show up and manually navigate the DOM in the debugging tool without interacting with the date field anymore?

Comment: Do you know where you go this date picker from?

Comment: At the very least, you may want to specify which language bindings you are using.  Or post some of the code you're written to address the problem...

Comment: @GregBurghardt, input field is there for datepicker only, once you click on it, div gets visible as you can see it in 3rd screen shot but if i try click on that div, it gets vanishes. It doesn't find in DOM.

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that it is allowing the user to input the date in the field too as I can see input tag in the screenshot. In that case, you can still use sendtext which input a valid format required which is mm/dd/yyyy in your case. so for that you can use below code

```
`IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(option);
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("")).SendKeys("06/26/2019");
```

If you are not able to input then you need to perform click and then perform key actions as per your requirement. let me know by comment if you need help with a specific scenario with more details what action you want to make I can help

Comment: Thanks Krunal, But i tried sendKeys as well before posting this query. Its not working

Comment: Krunal, i could add date in that input field with below code spinet but when I am trying to save the form, its saying "Required field" where format is correct .

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
  js.executeScript("arguments[0].value ='"+"06/28/2019"+"'",getAddEventFormPerformanceDateInput());

Comment: Did you try using Actions to select a date from datepicker it can be a temporary workaround. You can use tabs to reach datepicker and up and down arrows to select a date. Let me know if you need action codes for tab and other keys. Meanwhile, if your website is hosted, you can give a URL so that I can try and help you better.